# Connection to daemon was invalidated

Tags: firebase, uiscrollview, uikit, webkit, uimenucontroller

My app is using Firebase Analytics and I believe starting in iOS 13.2 started getting the errors described here: [Why I get the console warning: [Process] kill() returned unexpected error 1 when I load a WKWebView in iOS13.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58321114/why-i-get-the-console-warning-process-kill-returned-unexpected-error-1-when)

I guess it wasn't a big deal

Since I planned for my app to go live in January, I began bigger tests in physical devices. I noticed after a while the app started to behave erratically, specially after receiving a **[general] Connection to daemon was invalidated** error. This doesn't occur in the simulator

Searching the internet I found a post that describes the same problem: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/124306

In my case, only Firebase seems to be calling WKWebView, but every time I open the UIMenuController I get the error described in the console and the app appears to be missing inputs. This is specially troublesome with UIScrollViews, which my app uses a lot. The pinch gesture seems to work at will. On an iPhone 6s, the issue isn't as noticeable, on an iPad, it's like a 50% chance the pinch gesture will work properly

Outside of removing Firebase, is there a way to mitigate this issue?

1 June 2020: The console message still persists, however, I have seemed to resolve the UIScrollView issue by deactivating delaysContentTouches, now the pinch gesture seems to work most of the time

23 October 2020 If anyone notices their app starting to behave erratically with no apparent reason I HIGHLY suggest to test it on an iOS 13 physical device if possible. Seems that Apple removed the warning from iOS 14, but testing it on iOS 13 you can pin point the exact reason after the warning appears in the console

Comment: Someone in the developer forums linked it to Objective-C, which I think may be the problem. I really wish Firebase was updated to Swift. Every time I look at the definition of something, it is all written in Objective-C 

Comment: @George_E That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @BryanBryce It's basically just written in outdated code.

Comment: @George_E How is Objective-C outdated? Apple still uses it all over the place.

Comment: @BryanBryce Oudated code on Firebase’s part, hence the errors. Doesn’t matter anyway, just stating!

Comment: I've created a new Swift Project, absolutely clean. Just added a textfield to the ViewController, no WKWebView, no Firebase, nothing... and I'm also getting that same warning in the console and don't know why. But it seems that's not a developer mistake, it comes from Apple.

Comment: Leemur, do you notice your app behaving strange after that? As I said, I only seem to be missing a lot of inputs with an iPad, don't know which devices other developers are using

Comment: "[general] Connection to daemon was invalidated" happened to me too on ipad. it does not happen in simulator. it happened when I touched a uilabel.

Comment: An update: the problem in STILL present in iOS 13.4

Comment: I can't seem to get around it too. I am having it while using keyboard in UISearchBar. As soon as I type the first letter.

Comment: Is there any noticeable impact on how your app works? Aside from the warning in the console?

Comment: Igor, yes, at least for me. As I said (and repeated in the Apple Developer Forum) it seems the app starts missing touch inputs after the warning. My app has a scroll view over the whole screen to zoom an image, on an iPad, after the warning is received the pinch gestures misses like 50-75% of the time, you can see how annoying it can be for an user that has no idea of the bug

Comment: is there any open bug regarding this issue reported to Apple ? because the issue is still there on iOS 13.5 devices (SwiftUI project), this issue messes up my UI in some screens which is very annoying to the user.

Comment: @JAHelia can you describe how it messes your UI? Does it also has to do with missing touch inputs?

Comment: I will create a new project and start to file a bug report, I will share this new project next week.

Comment: I figured it out its just a glitch in xcode when running on a personal device I ran on the simulator for me it works fine

Comment: Can confirm, seems to be an Xcode issue. My app in production has no issues with this, but running on a device from Xcode presents the problem.

Comment: Seems like iOS 14 removed the warning, but the problems it causes are still there. Now it is messing with an UISlider in one of my apps, only iOS 13 shows the message though

Answer (score 0):

Upon further testing, I've reduced the view down to a dead-simple UI view with a single SwiftUI TextField and the 'Connection to daemon was invalidated' still appears after I type the first character into the field. Soon thereafter the app crashes with a sigAbort. (So I don't think the reason is the UITextView wrapper I was using in the previous post). Once the invalidated message appears the app is doomed to crash, not right away but soon thereafter.

I have no idea what causes the 'invalidate' message and a Google search seems to imply that no-one else does either. Some folks appear to have made (experimental?) changes to their UI that stops the message but it appears to be impossible to determine a definite cause. (and like before it only occurs on a real phone)

Answer (score 0):

Same issue without using Firebase at all.  What I did: **Delete build folder and compile again**.  Issue does not appears again.

On Xcode:
Clean the Build Folder
This will delete all of the products and intermediate files in the build folder. To clean the build folder you can use the shortcut Command+Option+Shift+K or Menu Bar → Product → Hold Option Key → Clean build Folder.

On Flutter:
Just delete build folder.