# Ionic Cordova phonegap-plugin-push did work on IOS but stopped recently with 'kill() returned unexpected error 1'

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, wkwebview

I have added phonegap-plugin-push plugin to an ionic 4.10.2 about two months ago,
it worked and I left the project alone for a while,
now when I recompile it (I don't have the working version anymore) it doesn't work.

The only notable difference since then is the console messages:

```
kill() returned unexpected error 1
```

as I have read they have to do with WKWebview and it [was never been fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58321114/why-i-get-the-console-warning-process-kill-returned-unexpected-error-1-when),

but no one have ever mentioned it has anything to do with push notifications

I also get `PushPlugin skip badge`

I don't see any version changes in **package.json** that could indicate a change in versions of plugins.

```
{
  "name": "*******",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.13",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic-native/call-number": "^5.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/launch-navigator": "^5.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/push": "^5.19.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.7.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.9.0",
    "angular2-signaturepad": "^2.9.0",
    "call-number": "^1.0.1",
    "cordova-android": "8.1.0",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-actionsheet": "^2.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.3",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^3.4.0",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "^1.3.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": "0.0.2",
    "phonegap-plugin-multidex": "^1.0.0",
    "phonegap-plugin-push": "2.3.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": "^5.0.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~2.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": {
        "GOOGLE_API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID": "1234",
        "OKHTTP_VERSION": "3.+"
      },
      "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": {},
      "call-number": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-push": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

nothing have change with Firebase and Provisioning files either.

any ideas? did it happen to anyone else recently? or is it just a coincidence and I should put more effort in searching the problem elsewhere