# Xcode 11, iOS 13.2 - “libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt. c:1647: Could not retrieve region info” Map Error

Tags: mapkit, ios-simulator, xcode11, ios13.2

In the iOS simulator, when running my mapKit view, the debugger goes crazy with a long string of updates and the map never loads, but the GPS does.

This appears to have started after installing cocoa pods with Firebase and Facebook recently.

Initially, maps weren't loading at all in the simulator. I finally set `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable` per this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/39461256/12349248 but now I have this current error log of constant update requests.

I upgraded to Xcode version 11.2 but the problem still occurs.

What is the issue and how can I fix this?

[SCREENSHOT - My broken map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVH2s.png)

**MY CODE**

```
    ViewController.swift


import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    private var currentCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureLocationServices()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    private func configureLocationServices() {
        locationManager.delegate = self

        let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

        if status == .notDetermined {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        } else if status == .authorizedAlways || status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
           beginLocationsUpdate(locationManager: locationManager)
        }
    }

    private func beginLocationsUpdate(locationManager: CLLocationManager) {
    // turn on setting to show location if authorized
       mapView.showsUserLocation = true
       // accuracy of location data can choose precision
       locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
       locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }

    private func zoomToLatestLocation(with coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
//        sets center point with lat 10k meters and long same
        let zoomRegion = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 1000, longitudinalMeters: 1000)
        mapView.setRegion(zoomRegion, animated: true)
    }

}


extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    // method triggered when new location change
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print("did get latest location")

        guard let latestLocation = locations.first else {return}

        if currentCoordinate == nil {
            zoomToLatestLocation(with: latestLocation.coordinate)
        }

        currentCoordinate = latestLocation.coordinate
    }

    // grant or deny permissions for location services update
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        print("the status changed")
        if status == .authorizedAlways || status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
           beginLocationsUpdate(locationManager: manager)
        }
    }

}
```

**DEBUGGER**

```
2019-11-10 17:34:22.300628-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] Metal API Validation Enabled
2019-11-10 17:34:22.599313-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:1647: Could not retrieve region info
the status changed
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:34:25.931188-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:34:25.931801-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:34:27.136038-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:34:27.136486-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:34:28.350193-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:34:28.350591-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:34:29.564044-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:34:29.564495-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:34:30.775670-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:34:30.776112-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:34:31.980113-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:34:31.980526-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:34:33.195862-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:34:33.196359-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:34:34.400059-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:34:34.400455-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:34:35.602372-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:34:35.602987-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:34:36.819062-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:34:36.819490-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:34:38.048874-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:34:38.049440-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:34:39.245251-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:34:39.245715-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:34:40.464186-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:34:40.464524-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:34:41.680947-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:34:41.681341-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:34:42.885346-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:34:42.885747-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:34:44.091929-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:34:44.092361-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:34:45.307488-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:34:45.308118-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:34:46.511448-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:34:46.511837-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:34:47.728203-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:34:47.728606-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:34:48.935933-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:34:48.936592-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:34:50.130216-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:34:50.131015-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:34:51.336875-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:34:51.337695-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:34:52.544178-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:34:52.544668-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:34:53.746758-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:34:53.747165-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:34:54.970204-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:34:54.970642-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:34:56.384593-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:34:56.385090-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:34:57.523320-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:34:57.524130-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:34:58.713705-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:34:58.714094-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:34:59.935251-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:34:59.935675-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:35:01.155617-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:35:01.156057-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:35:02.371416-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:35:02.371855-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:35:03.579343-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:35:03.579755-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:35:04.796706-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:35:04.797520-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:35:06.009626-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:35:06.009954-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:35:07.226691-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:35:07.227072-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:35:08.450535-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:35:08.450921-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:35:09.660548-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:35:09.660938-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:35:10.872959-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:35:10.873356-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:35:12.080884-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:35:12.081286-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:35:13.288586-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:35:13.288942-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:35:14.511220-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:35:14.511628-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:35:15.709855-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:35:15.710252-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:35:16.924709-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:35:16.925105-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:35:18.132220-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:35:18.132618-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:35:19.348017-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:35:19.348399-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:35:20.551412-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:35:20.551809-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:35:21.757480-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:35:21.757902-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:35:22.976291-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:35:22.976686-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:35:24.188785-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:35:24.189290-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:35:24.698292-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155788] [ResourceLoading] TiledGEOResourceFetcher received failed Resource: 164.397.10 t:13 kt:0, 1
2019-11-10 17:35:24.698534-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155788] [ResourceLoading] Failed to load key: 164.397.10 t:13 kt:0 type: 13, -1001: NSURLErrorDomain
2019-11-10 17:35:25.190972-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155783] [ResourceLoading] TiledGEOResourceFetcher received failed Resource: 2638.6358.14 t:6 kt:0, 36
2019-11-10 17:35:25.191169-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155783] [ResourceLoading] Failed to load key: 2638.6358.14 t:6 kt:0 type: 6, -1001: NSURLErrorDomain
2019-11-10 17:35:25.192492-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155813] [ResourceLoading] TiledGEOResourceFetcher received failed Resource: 2638.6357.14 t:6 kt:0, 23
2019-11-10 17:35:25.192662-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155813] [ResourceLoading] Failed to load key: 2638.6357.14 t:6 kt:0 type: 6, -1001: NSURLErrorDomain
2019-11-10 17:35:25.194560-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155783] [ResourceLoading] TiledGEOResourceFetcher received failed Resource: 2637.6358.14 t:6 kt:0, 42
2019-11-10 17:35:25.194723-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155783] [ResourceLoading] Failed to load key: 2637.6358.14 t:6 kt:0 type: 6, -1001: NSURLErrorDomain
2019-11-10 17:35:25.196429-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155813] [ResourceLoading] TiledGEOResourceFetcher received failed Resource: 2637.6357.14 t:6 kt:0, 24
2019-11-10 17:35:25.196600-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155813] [ResourceLoading] Failed to load key: 2637.6357.14 t:6 kt:0 type: 6, -1001: NSURLErrorDomain
2019-11-10 17:35:25.241481-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155788] [ResourceLoading] TiledGEOResourceFetcher received failed Resource: 2637.6358.14 t:8 kt:0, 15
2019-11-10 17:35:25.241945-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155788] [ResourceLoading] Failed to load key: 2637.6358.14 t:8 kt:0 type: 8, -1001: NSURLErrorDomain
2019-11-10 17:35:25.244795-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155813] [ResourceLoading] TiledGEOResourceFetcher received failed Resource: 2637.6357.14 t:8 kt:0, 16
2019-11-10 17:35:25.244977-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155813] [ResourceLoading] Failed to load key: 2637.6357.14 t:8 kt:0 type: 8, -1001: NSURLErrorDomain
2019-11-10 17:35:25.254981-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155813] [ResourceLoading] TiledGEOResourceFetcher received failed Resource: 2638.6358.14 t:8 kt:0, 14
2019-11-10 17:35:25.255185-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155813] [ResourceLoading] Failed to load key: 2638.6358.14 t:8 kt:0 type: 8, -1001: NSURLErrorDomain
2019-11-10 17:35:25.257049-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155783] [ResourceLoading] TiledGEOResourceFetcher received failed Resource: 2638.6357.14 t:8 kt:0, 31
2019-11-10 17:35:25.257245-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155783] [ResourceLoading] Failed to load key: 2638.6357.14 t:8 kt:0 type: 8, -1001: NSURLErrorDomain
2019-11-10 17:35:25.277607-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155788] [ResourceLoading] TiledGEOResourceFetcher received failed Resource: 2638.6358.14 t:1 kt:0, 48
2019-11-10 17:35:25.277792-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155788] [ResourceLoading] Failed to load key: 2638.6358.14 t:1 kt:0 type: 1, -1001: NSURLErrorDomain
2019-11-10 17:35:25.278210-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155783] [ResourceLoading] TiledGEOResourceFetcher received failed Resource: 2638.6357.14 t:1 kt:0, 38
2019-11-10 17:35:25.278362-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155783] [ResourceLoading] Failed to load key: 2638.6357.14 t:1 kt:0 type: 1, -1001: NSURLErrorDomain
2019-11-10 17:35:25.279730-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155783] [ResourceLoading] TiledGEOResourceFetcher received failed Resource: 2637.6358.14 t:1 kt:0, 35
2019-11-10 17:35:25.279898-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155783] [ResourceLoading] Failed to load key: 2637.6358.14 t:1 kt:0 type: 1, -1001: NSURLErrorDomain
2019-11-10 17:35:25.280652-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155783] [ResourceLoading] TiledGEOResourceFetcher received failed Resource: 2637.6357.14 t:1 kt:0, 20
2019-11-10 17:35:25.280816-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155783] [ResourceLoading] Failed to load key: 2637.6357.14 t:1 kt:0 type: 1, -1001: NSURLErrorDomain
2019-11-10 17:35:25.281776-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155788] [ResourceLoading] TiledGEOResourceFetcher received failed Resource: 2637.6357.14 t:9 kt:0, 44
2019-11-10 17:35:25.281938-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155788] [ResourceLoading] Failed to load key: 2637.6357.14 t:9 kt:0 type: 9, -1001: NSURLErrorDomain
2019-11-10 17:35:25.283052-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155813] [ResourceLoading] TiledGEOResourceFetcher received failed Resource: 2638.6357.14 t:9 kt:0, 34
2019-11-10 17:35:25.283213-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155813] [ResourceLoading] Failed to load key: 2638.6357.14 t:9 kt:0 type: 9, -1001: NSURLErrorDomain
2019-11-10 17:35:25.284398-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155788] [ResourceLoading] TiledGEOResourceFetcher received failed Resource: 2638.6358.14 t:9 kt:0, 32
2019-11-10 17:35:25.284586-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155788] [ResourceLoading] Failed to load key: 2638.6358.14 t:9 kt:0 type: 9, -1001: NSURLErrorDomain
2019-11-10 17:35:25.285408-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155783] [ResourceLoading] TiledGEOResourceFetcher received failed Resource: 2637.6358.14 t:9 kt:0, 41
2019-11-10 17:35:25.285567-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155783] [ResourceLoading] Failed to load key: 2637.6358.14 t:9 kt:0 type: 9, -1001: NSURLErrorDomain
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:35:25.472356-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:35:25.473025-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:35:26.772724-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:35:26.773149-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
2019-11-10 17:35:27.683882-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Executing an update request
2019-11-10 17:35:27.684747-0800 MapKit101MF[42111:1155619] [Accessibility] Update request succeeded
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
did get latest location
```

Comment: Did you try to update mapView in the main queue?

Comment: same problem for me on apple watch!! any solutions?

Comment: Same problem - not using CocoaPods or Firebase

Comment: Simply running on device instead of simulator worked for me.

Comment: I had 2 of your errors "TailedGEOResourceFetcher" and "Failed to load key". The problem was solved with refreshing an Internet connection.