# Xcode raising Log tcp_input [C109:3]/tcp_input [C107:3]

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I found when making requests the log pops a lot logs like or similar to the following:

```
2020-03-27 14:06:10.966089+0800 
ProjectC[20844:8100184] [] tcp_input [C23:3] flags=[R] seq=3301246612, ack=0, win=0 state=LAST_ACK rcv_nxt=3301246612, snd_una=3639195287
```

However I don`t understand what these things mean, could anyone explain a little bit?

Comment: This question will give some help: [Hide strange unwanted Xcode logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800790/hide-strange-unwanted-xcode-logs)