# HomeKit: "Thread left active" log in xcode console

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, homekit, ios-homekit

In my app, I have added a HomeKit-enabled `accessory` to my `home` object. It's a lightbulb that I'm able to successfully turn on/off from the app.

However, every time I switch it on/off I get these logs in the Xcode console:

```
2020-06-02 11:07:07.753864-0700 HomeKitStarter[759:312859] [Activity] [writeValue:completionHandler: (C030358E-8F98-4E43-8E43-6E498B50D62C)] Thread left active (1): <NSThread: 0x283c54b40>{number = 1, name = (null)}

2020-06-02 11:07:08.638182-0700 HomeKitStarter[759:312859] [Activity] [writeValue:completionHandler: (0E28FC72-FDEE-4625-93A3-F5939F878CE5)] Thread left active (1): <NSThread: 0x283c54b40>{number = 1, name = (null)}

2020-06-02 11:07:09.418971-0700 HomeKitStarter[759:312523] [Activity] [writeValue:completionHandler: (8E371920-B6E6-4363-90C7-019C6FA82895)] Thread left active (1): <NSThread: 0x283c54b40>{number = 1, name = (null)}
```

Does anyone know why "Thread left active" is being logged?

And why the `UUID` changes on every write?

Comment: I reading a value with from a sensor and having a similar response.  **[-[HMCharacteristic readValueWithCompletionHandler:] Thread left active (1): <NSThread: 0x283194640>{number = 1, name = (null)}**

Comment: I don't know the whys, but if anybody wants to hide them, editing the Scheme as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39461256/4894980) works.