# iOS16.1 Mapkit [VKDefault] Exceeded Metal Buffer threshold of 50000

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, metal, ios16

So for our maps, we are using MapKit. We overlay a layer using MKPolygons above the map. This feature has been working since iOS15 but since 16.1 we get the following error and the app freezes (does not crash).

- `[VKDefault] Exceeded Metal Buffer threshold of 50000 with a count of 50892 resources, pruning resources now (Time since last prune:6.497636): Assertion with expression - false : Failed in file - /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/VectorKit/src/MDMapEngine.mm line - 1363`
- `Metal API Validation Enabled [PipelineLibrary] Mapping the pipeline data cache failed, errno 22`

Another interesting log is the following

- `[IconManager] No config pack found for key SPR London Landmarks`

Any idea how to manually clear the metal cache?

Comment: Seems to be an issue present with or without polygons. Someone else posted below a comment I made and found the same issue, without polygons https://stackoverflow.com/a/74316787/2472466

Answer (score 5):

There seems to be a problem related to the number of MKOverlayRenderers making draw calls. Having more than a few seems to trigger this issue. Using MKMultiPolyline/Polygon seems to be a workaround but that does not work if you need to support iOS 12 or style the lines and polygons independently.

Comment: For me using a MKMultiPolyline renderer seems to have fixed the issue. Thank you!

Comment: @cjnorris @finn My project already uses `MKPolylineRenderer`, `MKPolygonRenderer`, and `MKMultiPolygonRenderer` but have started seeing the app freeze completely since iOS 16. Would you be able to share sample code to help me understand where I might be going wrong with this at all? Thanks

Comment: @mylogon I think the solution right now is to only use MKMultiPolygonRender and MKMultiPolylineRender, i.e. batching as many of your polygons and polylines together. In my testing I experience crashes when reaching only a couple of 100 renderers.

Comment: @mylogon not sure if you already fixed your issue, but I basically consolidated all similar polygons into one `MKMultiPolygon`

Comment: @derickito Thanks. This looks to be the official advice given to me by Apple DTS support too. Apparently iOS 16 mapkit has gained a lot of extra details and features (overhead), so this renderer performance issue is more likely to show on iOS 16 compared to previous releases.

Comment: I can confirm, that using MKMultiPolylineRenderer solved the issue. It seems that if you have several hundred of MKPolylineRenderers on iOS 16, then Metal will break.

Comment: It looks like Apple is aware at least. The iOS 16.4 Beta might actually fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

I was reading through this Apple Developer thread: [Drawing MKPolylines on map make app unresponsive.  Anybody else have this problem ?](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/719084) and I think [this answer](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/719084?answerId=744540022#744540022) could be interesting for you to find a solution for your problem. As I am currently also working on it, I will let you know when I have a solution.